# Can I create a video controller/ overlay in LiveCode

Tags: livecode

I have been using LiveCode for a couple of weeks now and have a question.
I would like to create a custom video controller with play, stop, rewind etc with LiveCode that shows and hides at the bottom of the screen if you touch the video currently playing in the video player on a mobile device. 
I have created the menu page with a selection of 4 videos to choose from and selecting any video goes to the next card and plays the video. On completing the video it goes to the previous card allowing the next selection. The video controls on the Quicktime player with LiveCode are rather crude and I would like to create a better looking interface. Is this possible with LiveCode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Look at the following commands and functions in the dictionary:

- start command
- stop command
- playStopped message
- currentTime property
- currentTimeChanged property
- playLoudness property

In addition, make sure to look at what's in each entries "see also" list.